# Own IOT platform using websockets

Tags: arduino, phpwebsocket

I am doing an IOT platform for my final year project at university, the concept is to link an IoT device with the Platform using WebSockets. My Websocket is working very well and I can send message from server to client.
But I don't know how to connect two clients to send messages to others via websocket server.

I can send message between website and server and also between my esp8266 and server.
how can I connect my arduino to the website?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any site containing a code?

Comment: If someone here can find the site "containing a code," you can too.  Asking for off-site references is *explicitly off-topic* here.

Comment: you must use your `server` as a contact point between all client and members.

Answer (score 0):

- A WebSocket is basically a persistent connection between a client and
  server.
- In order for devices to talk with each other they first need to pass
  by the server.
- The server simply redirects the messages to the client that needs to
  receive it.
- Generally you'd have the WebSocket server in your backend.
- Your frontend will be a WebSocket client.
- Your device will be another WebSocket client.